# Please unlink LaTeX editor for Windows and OpenID replacement question

Tags: support, linked-questions

I found that these two questions are linked but could not find anything common in between them.

[Best LaTeX editor for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/270121/177116)

[If OpenID “is dead”, what is out there to take its place? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4230821/177116)

Kindly unlink them if they are totally unrelated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are automatically linked because of [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230821/if-openid-is-dead-what-is-out-there-to-take-its-place#comments-4230821):

[image: Comment by rockinthesixstring]